# weblogic is running (without asking username and password) but Oracle form doesn't open, 404 Error occures

Tags: oracle, weblogic, http-status-code-404

I have a issue in Oracle WebLogic and don't know how to go through it. Please Help. 
First I start the WebLogic and it gives no error and turns into running state without asking username and password.

Then if I go to **http://vm-pc:7001/forms/frmservlet** then following page displays:

```
    Error 404--Not Found 
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found
The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
```

Moreover, **http://vm-pc:7001/console/login/LoginForm.jsp** links works correctly, ask me username and password and then shows me the health of my adminserver **100% OK and Running**

Please help me what I am missing ..

Thanks

Last lines from AdminServer.log

```
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426719869> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY> 
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426719884> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
####<> <Info> <SAFService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426719931> <BEA-281003> <SAF Service has been initialized.> 
####<> <Info> <SAFService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426719962> <BEA-281002> <SAF Service has been started.> 
####<> <Info> <WseeCore> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426719994> <BEA-220502> <The Wsee Service is starting> 
####<> <Info> <Deployer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720072> <BEA-149209> <Resuming.> 
####<> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720306> <BEA-000256> <Invoking weblogic.transaction.internal.StartupClass.main(null)> 
####<> <Info> <Diagnostics> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720384> <BEA-320000> <The Diagnostics subsystem is initializing on Server AdminServer.> 
####<> <Info> <Store> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720400> <BEA-280008> <Opening the persistent file store "WLS_DIAGNOSTICS" for recovery: directory=C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\data\store\diagnostics requestedWritePolicy="Disabled" fileLockingEnabled=true driver="wlfileio3".> 
####<> <Info> <Store> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720400> <BEA-280103> <The persistent file store "WLS_DIAGNOSTICS" will cache in weblogic.store.io.file.direct.FileMapping[granularity=65536 io=mapped].> 
####<> <Info> <Store> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720572> <BEA-280009> <The persistent file store "WLS_DIAGNOSTICS" (f1c1e427-9a57-4a60-94ba-ebb09401a1b3) has been opened: blockSize=512 actualWritePolicy="Disabled(single-handle-non-direct)" explicitIOEnforced=false records=23.> 
####<> <Info> <Log Management> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720697> <BEA-170025> <Initialized Domain Logging. Domain log events will be written to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs/base_domain.log.> 
####<> <Notice> <Log Management> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426720728> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
####<> <Info> <Diagnostics> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426721369> <BEA-320077> <Initialized the Diagnostic Accessor Service.> 
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426722056> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
####<T> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426722947> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
####<> <Info> <Management> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426722947> <BEA-141052> <The auto deployment poller has started.> 
####<> <Warning> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <DynamicListenThread[Default[2]]> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "VM-PC", maps to multiple IP addresses: 127.0.0.1, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1> 
####<> <Info> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-002610> <Dynamic Listener Service initialized.> 
####<> <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<> <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<> <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723103> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "base_domain" running in Development Mode> 
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723259> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
####<> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426723259> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
####<> <Info> <J2EE> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426726369> <BEA-160151> <Registered library Extension-Name: bea_wls_async_response (JAR).> 
####<> <Info> <EJB> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426727213> <BEA-010008> <EJB Deploying file: mejb.jar> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730004> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseServiceHttps for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730676> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseServiceJms for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730692> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseService for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730707> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseServiceSoap12Jms for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730723> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseServiceSoap12 for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <WebService> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426730723> <BEA-220103> <Async web service support is not fully configured. The async response web service /AsyncResponseServiceSoap12Https for this server was not fully deployed because the JMS reliability queue was not defined/deployed: weblogic.wsee.DefaultQueue. The server will periodically retry completing the deploy for the service. This message can usually be ignored unless there are async web service applications. To completely disable async web service support, thus avoiding this message, set -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true.> 
####<> <Info> <EJB> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473426730989> <BEA-010009> <EJB Deployed EJB with JNDI name ejb.mgmt.MEJB.> 
####<> <Info> <Health> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473426781812> <BEA-310002> <89% of the total memory in the server is free> 
####<> <Info> <WorkManager> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1473427794505> <BEA-002901> <Creating WorkManager "consoleWorkManager" for module "null" and application "consoleapp"> 
####<> <Info> <netuix> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473427798711> <BEA-423101> <[console] Initializing the NetUIx container> 
####< <Info> <netuix> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473427799602> <BEA-423120> <WEB-INF/client-classifications.xml file not found at uri [console//WEB-INF/client-classifications.xml]. Classifications functionality not enabled.> 
####<> <Info> <netuix> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473427800464> <BEA-423101> <[consolehelp] Initializing the NetUIx container> 
####<> <Info> <netuix> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473427800636> <BEA-423120> <WEB-INF/client-classifications.xml file not found at uri [consolehelp//WEB-INF/client-classifications.xml]. Classifications functionality not enabled.> 
####<> <Info> <Health> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1473427872292> <BEA-310002> <62% of the total memory in the server is free>
```

Comment: Well, do you actually have a servlet depolyed with that resource path?  Did you look in the server log?

Comment: I have two files .. AdminServer.log and base_domain.log ... how do I check ... ? both files have too many character which could not be inserted here. What value or line in log file should be required for review ?

Comment: I added some log information .. please see

Comment: So if you login to the admin console, and look under deployments, what do you see?

Comment: Nothing Sir. the table is empty. Please see image [link](http://s521.photobucket.com/user/m-awaidus/media/Under%20Deployment_zpspwh5szzh.gif.html)

Comment: So you have nothing deployed to the server but expect access to a servlet  that does not seem to exist to do something???  Why then do you think that forms/frmservlet should work?

Comment: I don't know how to handle this. I just start learning the Oracle 11g Forms & Reports ... What I am missing.. ? At least WebLogic (from command prompt) should ask me for username and password but it doesn't..

Comment: Don't know anything about Oracle forms.  Maybe re-read the documentation??